# What does "The dwarfdump binary must exist and must be executable" mean?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to build an app for submission to the AppStore..

Each time I try to build it I get a warning during Validate saying:

> The dwarfdump binary must exist and
>   must be executable: /usr/bin/dwarfdump
>   (-19036)

And Apple doesn't allow me to submit the app binary because of this warning. Does anyone know what's wrong?

I tried to Google it but I can't find anything useful..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was getting this error, but re-installed Xcode this time including the Unix tools (due to a suggestion on the iOS developer forums). This solved the problem. Previously I wasn't including this because I figured i wouldn't use it and was an extra 800MB of space used up. Seems iOS builds needs it for this one file now.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 78):

Try to search for the file *dwarfdump* on your computer(i.e. using spotlight). In my case it was located in */Developer/usr/bin*. Make a symbolic link into */usr/bin*

```
sudo ln -s /Developer/usr/bin/dwarfdump /usr/bin/
```

Answer (score 3):

Same situation here:

> Xcode 3.2.5 and iOS 4.2
>   (comes withApplication Loader 1.4)

So, I just tried and success to upload my app via **Application Loader ver 1.3** with no dwarfdump kind error

ver 1.3 can be downloaded link below:
https://itunesconnect.apple.com/apploader/ApplicationLoader_1.3.dmg

Comment: this worked for me, while the symlink solution mentioned here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173672/what-does-the-dwarfdump-binary-must-exist-and-must-be-executable-mean/4729482#4729482) did not! thanks!

Comment: in my situation it was also all about Application Loader - I had Xcode and iOS beta installed alongside my main Xcode env and launching Application Loader caused the other beta to take precedence... (which actually overrode my xcode-select setting!). Glad I solved this all myself by just uninstalling beta stuff and reinstalling stable stuff :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing /usr/bin/dwarfdump doesn't exist on your system.

Which Xcode Tools version do you have installed? Is it a stable release or one of the previews? My guess is the latter. The 3.2.5 GM seed has a warning attached on the ADC site you should read. I think it might be your problem.

Answer (score 0):

after upgrading to a SSD recently and migrating from my previous hard drive i got this error trying to upload my first app after the upgrade.

The solve was to delete "Application Loader" and reinstall it. solved.

some people are reporting you need to re install Xcode to get this error fixed but I found you only need to reinstall application loader. I guess and complete reinstall of Xcode will by default reinstall application loader and it will fix your issue but it's not necessary from my experience.

Comment: I reinstalled Application Loader 1.3 from satoko's link above, but that didn't fix the problem and made Xcode crash whenever I tried to upload. I couldn't find an installer for Application Loader 1.4, so I just reinstalled Xcode 3.2.5 and that fixed the problem for me.