# what is dwarfdump error?

Tags: objective-c, ios4, ipad

Anyone have a clue what this error means and how to fix it?

2011-02-03 16:11:54.729 Validation[8584:607] *** Warning: Defaulting to the standard codesign tool
warning: The dwarfdump binary must exist and must be executable: /usr/bin/dwarfdump (-19036)
Unable to validate your application. - (null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this page, you might be able to fix this by adding a symlink to dwarfdump. However, that didn't work for me and I ended up reinstalling Xcode, which did work.

[What does "The dwarfdump binary must exist and must be executable" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173672/what-does-the-dwarfdump-binary-must-exist-and-must-be-executable-mean)