# App Loader config directory permissions issue

Tags: objective-c, ios4, xcode4

I've created an iOS 4.3 iPhone app in Xcode 4.  When I use the Application Loader, I get this error:

Unable to create configuration directory:
/Users/myusername/.itmstransporter

I'm not sure it is permissions but believe it most likely is.  Any ideas how to resolve it?

It seems similar to [What does "The dwarfdump binary must exist and must be executable" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173672/what-does-the-dwarfdump-binary-must-exist-and-must-be-executable-mean), which I ran

sudo ln -s /Developer/usr/bin/dwarfdump /usr/bin/

and resolved that issue.

Comment: You've asked *a lot* of questions already, and I notice that there are a lot of them having good/correct answers. Please reward the people who have helped you and accept more answers. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

VanceG's answer got me to a solution, which was to change the permissions on my /Users/myusername folder to allow writing (the link he refers to does the same for the /Users/Shared folder which not surprisingly didn't solve this error as the app is complaining about writing to my user folder).

In terminal sudo chmod 777 /Users/myusername (or chmod 1777 depending on version of OSX as discussed in http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1277).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and it turned out to be a problem with the Shared users folder, which also was causing problems with iTunes home sharing. For me, following these instructions fixed both problems: http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1277

Hope it works for you too.